# How do I Refresh my shortcut file in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, powershell, windows-8.1

OK so I was trying to change the color of the tiles in Win 8.1 and came across this link
[Customising Start Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx)

However I didn't understood the Step 7 and have no idea what do do that. I created the file and copied at the installation directory but the tile color won't change and I don't know how to use that powershell.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is sortof a souped-up version of NTVDM (the DOS shell still in Windows). Swipe in, select "Search" and enter PowerShell. Open it and enter the command that MSDN provides, changing their example to the one that you have made, hit enter, and it should work.

If throws a permissions error, you might need to close PowerShell and then open it again as an administrator. This will involve going through a UAC prompt.

Comment: I copy pasted the code but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you change the path to point to your file?